# Developing Flash games on the Wii

Tags: actionscript, flash, wii

Has anyone used [WiiFlash](http://wiiflash.bytearray.org/) for developing Flash games? Any pointers on how to begin developing games for the Opera channel for the Wii?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WiiFlash project was for using the wiimote on PC/Mac games. I think you want to look at the MarioToo project for creating wii browser games. To be honest though, why bother? You've got a much bigger audience to target with Flash by going for the general PC/Mac/Linux audience.

Comment: Well, you know, you sometimes just want to tinker with things ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that the Internet Channel (Opera browser) uses Adobe Flash Lite 3.1; Basically Flash 8 with some Flash 9 features.

I would perhaps target the Wii but make the game accessible to any browser.  Best of both worlds.  Think of it more like a regular browser on an ancient machine using the Flash 8 plugin and you shouldn't have too much trouble.

I've never used WiiFlash but it might be interesting for testing locally; If you have a Wii already you'd be better off setting up a local webserver and pointing the Wii browser to that local address for testing.

If you were ever going to do a 3D game you'd have to drop Flash entirely and go with [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com) or some similar engine.

Answer (score 2):

As @Iain mentioned, that is not why the WiiFlash was made.

You will be using actionscript 2.0 to make Flash Games for the WII.
There is a title out there on this subject:[Nintendo Wii Flash Game Creator's Guide](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Q1AQZ0oI9BcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=developing+flash+games+for+wii&hl=en&ei=9YRPTIW6GI6V4gaHyayrCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=developing%20flash%20games%20for%20wii&f=false)

HTH

Answer (score 1):

For Wii games, you might want to check out [**Unity**](http://unity3d.com/). It's pretty easy to work with and has portability to the Wii that you can buy.

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other Flash game, just play test it a lot on the Opera channel to make sure that it fits that rather than your browser. Please note that a Flash game can not detect all buttons and swings...